# Filters & foreign key error : "The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing."

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to filter products based on the logged in user. These products are however not linked to the user directly, but to the user's company.

And the user's profile is linked to the user's company.

To allocate a product the allocator would follow this process:

1. Go to `RFQ` model - select a product
2. Select 1 or many `Supplier Profiles`
3. Validates and creates an Enquiry
4. Once the Enquiry is created, a user of the Supplier Profile would then be able to see what has been allocated

I would normally use the pk_id of the company to return this, but on this occasion I need to find an alternative.

I am struggling to get my head around all these interactions and how can the `filter()` can be applied to what I am trying to achieve.

The current code I came up with returns the following error: `The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.` This is probably due to the for loop in the template.

**model**

```
class Supplier_Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Supplier Profile', max_length=120, blank=True)

class Supplier_User_Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    supplier_company = models.ForeignKey(Supplier_Profile,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class RFQ(models.Model):
    rfq_name = models.ForeignKey(Product,blank=True,  null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    suppliers_consulted = models.ManyToManyField(Supplier_Profile)

class Enquiry(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(RFQ, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views**

```
def list_supplier_response(request):
    supplier_profile = Supplier_Profile.objects.all()
    enquiries = Enquiry.objects.filter(name__suppliers_consulted=supplier_profile)
    return render(request, 'main/list_supplier_response.html',{'supplier_profile':supplier_profile,'enquiries':enquiries})
```

**template**

```
{% for enquiry in enquiries.all %}
        <td><a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="">{{enquiry.name}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing (`The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing`) Is due to the fact there are probably multiple supplier profiles. You need to use the `__in` method

```
def list_supplier_response(request):
    supplier_profile = Supplier_Profile.objects.all()
    enquiries = Enquiry.objects.filter(name__suppliers_consulted__in=supplier_profile)
    return render(request, 'main/list_supplier_response.html',{'supplier_profile':supplier_profile,'enquiries':enquiries})
```

As a side note you don't need to write `.all` after a value from the context.

I also didn't see the Enquiry model in the ones provided but I assume it's somewhere in your code. :)

Regarding your template you should probably change `{{enquiry.name}}` to `{{enquiry.name.rfq_name}}` if you want it to display anything.

Comment: Thanks, this removes the error so thats a good start. However, I am still getting all the enquiries listed and not those specific to the `supplier_profile` to which the product has been allocated. (The supplier_user_profile connected to the relevant `supplier_profile` will then be able to see them) Any suggestion?